# Where Static class is preferred?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, class, static-classes

Why we use static class? As newbie I understand

**(Correct me if i am wrong please.)**

- we don't have to create the instant of class and use data member and methods it by name.
- Any other class can't inherit it
- We **only** have static methods and static data members in it

While in normal class

- we can also have static members and static methods.
- And call them with the name of class

Then why static class is preferred?
OR
Where Static class is preferred?

Comment: “Almost never..” save for some root types - prefer Dependency Injection. It makes testing *much* easier. (Don’t worry about inheritance: it’s usually overused..)

Answer (score 8):

[From MSDN:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)

why static class is preferred? OR Where Static class is preferred?

> A static class can be used as a convenient container for sets of
>   methods that just operate on input parameters and do not have to get
>   or set any internal instance fields. For example, in the .NET
>   Framework Class Library, the static System.Math class contains methods
>   that perform mathematical operations, without any requirement to store
>   or retrieve data that is unique to a particular instance of the Math
>   class.

Answer (score 0):

A static class cannot be instantiated. All members of a static class are static and are accessed via the class name directly, without creating an instance of the class.

Static classes have the following characteristics:

- Static classes cannot contain Instance Constructors.
- Static classes contain only static members.
- Static classes cannot be instantiated.
- Static classes are sealed. That means, you cannot inherit other
  classes from instance classes.
  You can use Static class for Extension for any class and also Some methods you want use entire solution.

Comment: The question was "Where Static class is preferred?" - how does this go any way to answering WHEN a static class should be used?